# How to create a PHP tunnel script based on sockets?

Tags: php, sockets

I tried to implement a PHP script that opens two sockets:

1. `sock1` as a server socket to be connected from the outside
2. `sock2` as a client socket to an internal service that cannot be connected from the outside

Data read from the outside should be written to the inside and the other way round.
Finally I stopped my work with basically the following code. Attention: this is not working robustly. I got some requests back and forth but struggled with hanging socket_read or unsuccessful socket_write operations most of the time.

How to implement the bidirectional in <-> out communication based on sockets correctly?

```
<?php

$sock1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,  SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket 1");
socket_bind($sock1, "127.0.0.1", 10001) or die("Could not bind to socket 1");
socket_listen($sock1, 0) or die("Could not set up socket 1 listener");

$sock2 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,  SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket 2");
socket_connect($sock2, "127.0.0.1", 10002);

$sock3 = socket_accept($sock1);
socket_set_nonblock($sock3);

while (!feof($sock3)) {

    while(true) {
        $extread = socket_read($sock3, 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ);
        if ($extread===FALSE || strlen($extread)==0) break;
        $result = socket_write($sock2, $extread);
        if ($result===FALSE) {
            break;
        }
    }

    while(true) {
        $dbread = socket_read($sock2, 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ);
        if ($dbread===FALSE || strlen($dbread)==0) break;
        $result = socket_write($sock3, $dbread);
        if ($result===FALSE) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

fclose($sock3);
fclose($sock2);
fclose($sock1);
```